# Astropy 'Time' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: astropy, dtype

Since updating to [Astropy 4.0](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/whatsnew/4.0.html), attempts to access the `dtype` of a [`Time`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.time.Time.html#astropy.time.Time) object result on the error

> 'Time' object has no attribute 'dtype'

I've read through the documentation, but can't find mention of this change, or how to replicate the functionality that it provided. Prior to the update, such access returns values like `object` or `float64`.

How do I retrieve the `dtype` of an Astropy 4.0 `Time` instance?

Answer (score 2):

What version of Astropy are you upgrading from? I can't find any recent version where there was a (documented) `Time.dtype` attribute.  In the previous version:

```
>>> import astropy
>>> astropy.__version__
'3.2.3'
>>> from astropy.time import Time
>>> t = Time([1, 2, 3], format='unix')
>>> t.dtype
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/embray/.virtualenvs/astropy/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/time/core.py", line 1558, in __getattr__
    return self.__getattribute__(attr)
AttributeError: 'Time' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

There is, however:

```
>>> t.value.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

where [`Time.value`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.time.Time.html#astropy.time.Time.value) gives the underlying numpy array for the values (which could be a bit better documented perhaps).

I'm not sure that there was ever a `Time.dtype`, or if there was it must have been in a much older version.

Comment: I'd been using Astropy 3.1.2, which produced values (usable as strings) like `Time` or `float64`.

Comment: What do you mean by "produced values usable as strings"? Do you have an example?

Comment: What do you mean by "it appears I am looking for `._format`"?  You should not be using that: In Python, attributes that begin with an underscore typically mean that they're internal implementation details that should not be used directly.  You probably want the public attribute [`Time.format`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.time.Time.html#astropy.time.Time.format).  And that's totally different from the `dtype`.

Comment: Correct, sorry. `Time.format` works. My problem is that the code where this occurs was written when I was first learning Python with an astronomy project as motivation, so it's not the best context. For years (until this month) `dtype` provided the information I wanted (I've been updating packages pretty regularly) and then suddenly it didn't. `format` does the trick, though as you say, it's not isomorphic with `dtype` generally.

Comment: Not even non-generally; it's a completely different thing.  The `Time.format` attribute specifies what time format is being represented, as there are many.  E.g. `'unix'` means seconds since 1/1/1970 where as `'jd'` is Julian Date in days.  The `dtype` of a Numpy array is a numerical data type such as integer or float; with Time objects there's no way to know how to interpret the numerical values without reference to a specific time format.  I'd be curious to see this code that you say worked because there is no `Time.dtype` attribute...

Comment: Also, it's not my intention here to nitpick--I just really want to make sure you're using the correct approach to whatever your problem is...

Answer (score 2):

The `Time` object never had a dtype since the `Time` class does not inherit from `np.ndarray`.

As mentioned by @Iguananaut you might have been looking at the `value` or other format attribute (e.g. `t.iso.dtype`).

Another place to find a `dtype` is in the `info` property `t.info.dtype`, but that is always just Object and is used when a `Time` object is stored in a `Table`.

Comment: I'd been using Astropy 3.1.2, which produced values (usable as strings) like `Time` or `float64`.